# Git-based website deployment workflow

Tags: git, workflow, nginx, hook

On my server, I have two users, `www-data` (which is used by nginx) and `git`. The `git` user owns a repository that contains my website's code, and the `www-data` user owns a clone of that repository (which serves as the webroot for nginx). I want to set up a workflow such that pushing to `git`'s repository causes `www-data`'s repository to update, thus updating my website.

What is the correct way to set up the hooks for these repositories (that also takes into consideration privileges and permissions of these two users)?

Comment: Is it really a good idea to have all your public content owned by the user account that runs the server? If the server or your code is exploited, the exploit could modify persistent data, rather than just have access to scribble on your database connections...

Comment: Then should I make the public content owned by `git`, and make it readable by everyone? That would also simplify the permission issues in this question...

Comment: _If_ you're content with it as a solution, then yes, it would save you the hassle of finding a new way to push from `git` to `www-data` repos. :) Do you prefer having two git repos on the server? Another option is to set the group ownership of the files to be one of the server's groups, and allow read access through group privileges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the repository owned by `www-data` and follow the solution on this [webpage](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) for setting up a post-receive hook in the repository owned by `git`.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up making the public content owned by the `git` user, and readable by all. Then, I did the following to set up the hooks:

Assuming the repository is called `mysite`:

1. Create a detached work tree that will act as the webroot (as the user `git`)

   ```
   mkdir /var/www/mysite
   cd /path/to/repository/mysite.git
   git config core.worktree /var/www/mysite
   git config core.bare false
   git config receive.denycurrentbranch ignore
   ```
2. Add a post-receive hook that will update the website and set correct permissions for it

   ```
   touch hooks/post-receive
   chmod +x hooks/post-receive
   vim hooks/post-receive
   ```

   The post-receive script:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   git checkout -f
   chmod -R o+rX /var/www/mysite
   ```

Reference:
http://www.deanoj.co.uk/programming/git/using-git-and-a-post-receive-hook-script-for-auto-deployment/

---

Update: Here is a [better solution](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto).

> Note: earlier versions of this howto depended on setting the git config variables core.worktree to the target directory, core.bare to false, and receive.denycurrentbranch to ignore. But these changes are not needed if you use GIT_WORK_TREE (which didn't work when I first wrote the howto), and the remote repository can remain bare.

Comment: Ack why do people keep finding all of these nasty solutions people blog about instead of the proper ones.

Comment: @Arrowmaster: Thanks, simpler is always better.