# Making www-data push to local git repo

Tags: php, linux, git, drupal, hosting

So, I'm creating a system which manages all the drupal websites that sit within a specific folder (new websites can be created in this folder).

The next step is to create a way to allow the user to revert the website to a prior version.

My solution? Create a local "git server" and for every action taken on my system (e.g.: update/install modules, upgrade the core, etc) I create a new version of that site.

I created a "git" user which is responsible for the creation of repositories on `/~/gitrepos/`. And for each new website, I use `sudo -u git` within apache user (www-data) to run `mkdir` and `git init --bare`. I'm currently able to create new folders and to initialize git repositories on those.

But when I try to push the website changes to those repositories, I get "Permission denied".

When a new site is detected, I do the following:

1. Create the repository [using www-data and `sudo -u git`]

   - `mkdir` and `git init`
2. Initialize the git repository (.git folder) on the website directory [using www-data]

   - `git init`
3. Add the files to the commit queue [using www-data]

   - `git add *`
4. Commit the changes to populate the newly created repository [using www-data]

   - `git commit -m 'msg'`
5. Add the remote address of the repository [using www-data]

   - `git remote add origin ssh://git@localhost/path/to/repo/`
6. Push changes [using www-data]

   - `git push -u origin master`

And now I'm stuck on this step, as I always get "Permission denied".

There's any way for me to push changes to a local "git server" without the need to authenticate?

Or yet, which ssh-keys I should create to enable www-data to push changes to the local "git server"?

I'm really lost here, **if someone has a step-by-step way to setup a local "git server" in which the www-data user can push to, that would be great**.

Note: the home directory for www-data is `/var/www/`, so it's not a good idea to store ssh-keys in this directory

---

Yes, I have spent at least 4 hours trying to figure this out before asking here.

Some of the resources I tried to follow:

- http://www.hackido.com/2010/01/installing-git-on-server-ubuntu-or.html
- http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto
- http://pthree.org/2008/11/28/setup-a-git-repository/
- [Git-based website deployment workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439290/git-based-website-deployment-workflow)
- http://tumblr.intranation.com/post/766290565/how-set-up-your-own-private-git-server-linux
- http://blogs.gurulabs.com/aaron/2008/11/setup-a-git-repository.html

---

The reason why I quote "git server" is because there's no such thing as a git *server*.

Quote from http://blogs.gurulabs.com/aaron/2008/11/setup-a-git-repository.html :

> In other words, there's no such thing as a "git server" and "git client". Git was developed by filesystem developers with filesystem attributes in mind. So, instead, we have a remote Git repository we call the "origin" and a local Git repository (...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution:

**Assumptions:**

- Your `www-data` home directory is `/var/www/`
- The user that'll handle all git commands is `gituser`

**Steps:**

To make the `www-data` user push changes to the git repo without the need to type the password, just:

- Create a new ssh-key for the www-data user

  - `www-data:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa`
  - press `enter` for every question (leave the password blank)
- Add the newly created ssh-key onto `/home/gituser/.ssh/authorized_keys`

  - `gituser:~$ touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
  - `gituser:~$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
  - `gituser:~$ cat /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/gituser/.ssh/authorized_keys`

The idea behind that, is to add `www-data`'s ssh-key to `gituser`'s "trusted" keys. After that, `www-data` will be able to connect to the server via ssh and authenticate as `gituser` without the need to type the password.

Remember that git requires ssh access to the server (at least on the environment that I'm at).

This might help: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html